# Wordpress Plugin Admin Tab

Tags: admin

I'm not sure on the terminology because a Google search isn't really sending me in the right direction.

I currently have a WordPress Plugin which is inside the settings tab.

I would like to have my own tab which has 3 subsections underneath it.

I've tried looking at these:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'jobboard_admin_actions');
function jobboard_admin_actions() {
add_options_page('JobBoard', 'JobBoard', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'JobBoard_admin');
}
```

But I'm still stuck.

Thanks,

Changes :

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'jobboard_admin_actions');
function jobboard_admin_actions() {
add_menu_page('JobBoard', 'JobBoard', 'manage_options', JobBoard_admin,  'JobBoard_admin', '');
add_submenu_page( 'JobBoard_admin', 'JobBoard', 'JobBoard', 'manage_options',    'JobBoard_admin', 'JobBoard_admin_delete' ); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I used:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'manage_poll_menu' );
function manage_poll_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'Manage Polls', 'Polls', 'manage_polls_cap', 'manage_polls', 'my_poll_options', '' );
    add_submenu_page( 'manage_polls', 'Add New', 'Add New Poll', 'manage_polls_cap', 'add_new_poll', 'my_poll_options' );
    add_submenu_page( 'manage_polls', 'Poll Sections', 'Poll Sections', 'manage_polls_cap', 'poll_sections', 'my_poll_options' );
    add_submenu_page( 'manage_polls', 'Add New Poll Section', 'Add New Poll Section', 'manage_polls_cap', 'add_new_poll_section', 'my_poll_options' );
}
function my_poll_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_polls_cap' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }

    echo '<div class="wrap">Page content</div>';
}
```

Also more information about [Administration Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) and [Submenu Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) you can find on [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus).

Comment: Hey Spartakus, thanks for the read. Really useful stuff :)

Would you mind looking over something for me?

I have edited the OP. I have it working if I use your manage polls example, but if I change some of the values it doesn't show the subpage. 

Thanks.

Comment: Take attention to parent_slug `add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, ...)` it must be the same as menu_slug from `add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, ...)`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice to hear it!